# Authlogic with declarative authorizations - how to show the user role in the view?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authlogic, declarative-authorization, role

I'm using [declarative roles](http://railscasts.com/episodes/188-declarative-authorization), a Ryan Bates 'railscast' tutorial. I would like to show the role of the user who is logged in, in the view. Is there any variable I can use to display the name of the role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As that tutorial goes, a user "has many" roles, but you are not logged in as a particular role at any one time, you have all of them assigned to you, and all of those assigned are valid all at once.  They are linked from the user model:

```
models/user.rb

has_many :assignments
has_many :roles, :through => :assignments
```

So you could show all the roles with something like

```
<%= current_user.roles.join(', ') %>
```

Assuming that current_user is a helper method that gives the current logged in user model instance.

Comment: Thanks DGM for your reply, but from this one, how can I get the information, what is the role of the **current_user**? This is what I still don't understand

Comment: A user doesn't have just one role, but rather has all the roles as defined by the has_many :roles, :through => :assignments